# Selenium pressing "submit" button just redirects back to the same page

Tags: python, selenium, puppeteer

I am trying to login to my comcast account using selenium but its not pressing "sign in" button properly. What it does is, it just redirects you back to the old email page (it also removes the email typed in the input). I have tried waiting implicitly, waiting for button to be clickable, etc.
I have tried the same thing in Node.js with puppeteer and it works as expected.

Python code:

```py
driver.get("https://login.xfinity.com/login")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#user").send_keys(email+Keys.ENTER)
# there is more code but it can't even get pass the first email step
```

Node.js code:

```js
await page.goto("https://login.xfinity.com/login");
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
await page.type("#user", email);
await page.click("#sign_in");
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
await page.type("#passwd", password);
await page.click("#sign_in");
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
```

Comment: Did you try this? Python code:
`driver.find_element_by_id("user").send_keys(your_email_id)
`driver.find_element_by_id('sign_in').click()`

Comment: In the Python script your are pressing enter instead of click. Why?

Comment: I have tried clicking also but the same result

Comment: Silly question, but I am compelled to ask: Is the email id you are trying enter is correct? For if you enter an incorrect/unmatched email id, it gives this error `The Xfinity ID or password you entered was incorrect. Please try again.` and it sits on the same page.

Comment: Its correct and it does not shows anything, it basically redirects you back to the same page with everything cleared.

Comment: if you are struggling to test, please use "lanaimes@comcast.net" as email (it was my old acc which got disabled).

Comment: Looks like the website detects the bot actions (browser opening through selenium).  I tried manual entry on a normal browser as well as the browser invoked through webdriver, and I see that normal browser works fine, but the one invoked through webdriver does not. You may need to use a user agent or a proxy, but I am not sure about them. Sorry, can't help much here. Anyone else for a better suggestion here please?

Comment: @AnandGautam great testing, I think that's probably why puppeteer was working. I will try something tomorrow and test, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to wait at least 1 second after you type the password. This mimic human behavior - you type the password, wait a bit and then press the submit button.

```
await page.goto("https://login.xfinity.com/login");
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
await page.type("#user", email);
await page.click("#sign_in");
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
await page.type("#passwd", password);
// wait 1 second after typing the password
await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
await page.click("#sign_in");
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
```

Comment: hey there, I am having trouble with python code, not with puppeteer (I only used it to test because I am not good at selenium).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not referencing the object properly. There is a Firefox extension, TruePath. You can get the path to any object from that extension.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but it works as expected with puppeteer (node.js). I think this problem is either related to selenium or the website just assuming we are a bot

Comment: I don't think that's the case since it works for puppeteer perfectly fine.